# How to call this.superClassMethod on Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have the following code:

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    companion object {
        private val STREAM: String = "com.example.my_app/stream";

        private lateinit var EVENT_CHANNEL: EventChannel
        init {

            EVENT_CHANNEL = EventChannel(this.getFlutterEngine().getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), STREAM)
```

but I get `Unresolved reference: getFlutterEngine`, but the method exists: https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/embedding/android/FlutterActivity.html#getFlutterEngine()

I also tried `this@FlutterActivity.getFlutterEngine()` and `this@MainActivity.getFlutterEngine()`. I think the problem is that things are inside the Companion object.

How to call `getFlutterEngine?`

Comment: Your `this.getFlutterEngine` is inside the companion object, so there *is* no `MainActivity` instance to call it on at that point. Are you missing a closing brace somewhere, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is Pointing `MainActivity.companion`, not `MainActivity`, since you're calling inside of `companion object`

Seems like you are trying to achieve to make `EVENT_CAHNNEL` that can access from anywhere. You might need to think to change design.